# How to trim comma and dot before or after words

Tags: sql, asp.net, trim

net web project I am trying to insert all the words of a text with 3 paragraph.How ever if the sentence is like this

"This text is a test text."

Then last word goes database with dot. (text.)

```
 strNew = strNew.Trim(new Char[] { ' ', ',', '.', '?' });
```

I have tried this code but didnt help.Here is my all code.

```
            {int id = 0;
            ListBox1.Items.Clear();
            string strNew = Request.Form["TextBox1"];

            int n = strNew.Split(' ').Length;
            ListBox3.Items.Add(String.Format("Number of Words: {0}", n));

            int m = Regex.Matches(strNew, "[^\r\n]+((\r|\n|\r\n)[^\r\n]+)*").Count;//Counts Number of Paragraphes

            ListBox3.Items.Add(String.Format("Number of Paragraphes: {0}", m));
            strNew = strNew.ToLower();// all lower case
            strNew = strNew.Trim(new Char[] { ' ', ',', '.', '?' });
            var results = strNew.Split(' ').Where(x => x.Length > 1)
                                          .GroupBy(x => x)
                                          .Select(x => new { Count = x.Count(), Word = x.Key });//splitting sentences in to words



            using (con){
    con.Open();

    foreach (var item in results) {//here trying to insert word its id and some other informations but for now they can stay null(yes,null allowed for them)
        id++;
        string w = item.Word.ToString();
        SqlCommand cmd= con.CreateCommand();
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@word", item.Word);
        cmd.CommandText= "INSERT INTO word(id, word, sid, frequency, weight, f) VALUES (@id, @word, 0, 0, 0, 0) ";



       cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); 

    }
        con.Close();
}        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn't on a single line, is with multi paragraph splitting and trimming.

If you apply **Trim** it will only work on the start and end of the current line, not paragraph because the term paragraph is unknown in computer language string.

You should trim every line after splitting it to paragraphs.

**Example:** "This text is a test text.\r\nThis is another test."
The current operation will only trim the last `.` because `test.\r\nThis` will be identify as 1 word.

**Code:**

```
char[] trimCharacters = { ' ', ',', '.', '?' };
var results = strNew.Split(new string[] { " ", "\r\n", "\n" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                    .GroupBy(x => x)
                    .Select(x => new { Count = x.Count(), Word = x.Key.Trim(trimCharacters) });
```

Answer (score 0):

In fact there is no need to trim your strings.

```
    var matches = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Matches(strNew, @"(\b\w+\b)")
        .Cast<System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match>();
    var result = matches.GroupBy(m => m.Value)
        .Select(gr => new { Word = gr.Key, Count = gr.Count() });

    foreach (var r in result)
    {
        //do whatever you want with r.Word and r.Count
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you use strNew.TrimEnd('.') or TrimStart on each word after splitting?